# Pygame music player playing audio only once then throwing error

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to use pygame mixer to play audio files  as shown in my code below.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pygame import mixer
import urllib.request
from time import sleep

mixer.init()
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.freemusicloops.co.uk/download.aspx?did=266", "firstfile.wav")
audio1 = AudioSegment.from_wav("firstfile.wav")

mixer.music.load("firstfile.wav")
mixer.music.play()
```

However, I can only play the file once and then it gives the following error.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'firstfile.wav'
```

How can I fix this error and play the same audio multiple times without having to delete it and run the code again?

Comment: What do you mean play it multiple times? Do you want it to loop? You can do that by passing the number of how many times you want it to repeat, e.g. if I want my background track to repeat five times I'd write 'mixer.music.play(5)'.

Comment: I mean running the code multiple times. The first time I run it, it plays. Every other time after, it throws the error.

Comment: I just want to play it once each time it runs but it only works the first time.

Comment: What do you mean run the code multiple times? I don't see any loops? I don't know what you are trying to do, but you can either load the file and use it for the rest of your program and not call mixer.music.load() each time for the same file, because if you haven't unloaded it previously, then it's still being used and taking up resources. Which leads me to the second option and that is, at the end of your program you should just call ' mixer.music.unload()'. That's inefficient, however, and so is downloading the file each time you run thru your code.

Comment: Glad that helped! I'll post it as an answer; feel free to accept and close it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, if you are running your program again and again from the top, then the two solutions I see are either loading the file first and then containing the playing of it to an inner loop within your program (say, game loop) OR unloading the file at then of your program by calling

```
mixer.music.unload('filename')
```

where the 'filename' is the file you've loaded before.